# How to prevent moving text when resizing text above it?

Tags: css, html

I have created a test page and I have a problem.
I set that if I hover over sample 2, it will change it's font size.

```
#button:hover {
     background-color: pink;
     font-size: 15px; }
```

But if I hover over it, the sample 3 text moves down a little bit. How can I
disable absolute moving of sample 3 ? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well.

Comment: Give your sample 2 a fixed height, or give an absolute position to sample 3.

Comment: See this example https://jsfiddle.net/3x94rdcy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I hover over it (button), the sample 3 (assuming this is an element below button) text moves down a little bit.

Consider the following issue

You change the font size on hover and the entire layout including `sample3` which is an html element shifts downwards. See snippet below

```css
#button1,#button2{
   width:100px;
}
#button1:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="button1">
  Option1
</div>
<div id="#button2">
  Option2
</div>
```

One way you can strategically prevent your layout from shifting or glitching is

use a min-height on the divs that you apply that hover on

adjust line-height a bit so that elements centers in the middle

see snippet below

```css
#button1,
#button2 {
  min-height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height:2em;
}

#button1:hover,
#button2:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="button1">
  Option1
</div>
<div id="button2">
  Option2
</div>
```